# VS Cocoa - Error when trying to open Main.Storyboard: "id cannot be empty"

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, visual-studio-mac

Cannot find a solution or definition online anywhere about this which is ridiculous.

When attempting to open the Main.Storyboard from the solution explorer I get a popup error stating simply "id cannot be empty."

I have no idea where to find this "id" and how to solve this problem. From what I can tell, one other dude on the internet also has this problem and nobody posted a solution for him in the VS forums.

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

Go to **Tools->SDK Manager**

In the window which opens select **Projects->SDK Locations->Apple**

Ensure the Apple SDK Location is pointing to the correct Xcode.app location e.g. **/Applications/Xcode.app**

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue fixed just reboot my mac book.